# Phonegap db transaction error

Tags: database, cordova

I am running db queries to insert data into SQLite in Phonegap. Queries are totally ok, and the actual executeSql returned success, but the problem is the transaction function always call failure callback with the following error:

"the statement callback raised an exception or statement error callback did not return false"

And when I check the actual db, no data was inserted at all. This is really weird, any help towards the right direction thanks.

Comment: any sample code to start with?

Comment: My fault, it seem DB transaction need all callbacks to return true otherwise will cause error